# Using ipython no response

Tags: beautifulsoup, ipython, python-3.5, jupyter-notebook

I run this on jupyter, but no any response, I don't know the reason.

Can anyone help me with it?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get("https://s.taobao.com/search?q=%E5%92%96%E5%95%A1%E5%A3%B6&imgfile=&commend=all&ssid=s5-e&search_type=item&sourceId=tb.index&spm=a21bo.50862.201856-taobao-item.1&ie=utf8&initiative_id=tbindexz_20161013")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
for item in soup.select('.item'):
    print (item.select('strong')[0].text)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please read [ask] and [mcve] for asking better received questions. Finally on the last line you have '.item' , afaik this will select exactly the text .item and not the variable item.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, `soup.select('.item')` performs a CSS selection operation on the `soup` object, and returns blank list `[]`.
Hence, nothing is available to print.

Try the following code instead to get some results to work on:

```
for each in soup.select('.list-mod'):
    print repr(each)
    # more code here
```

I tried and the result is

```
<div class="list-mod" data-module="baseItem" id="list-baseItem"></div>
<div class="list-mod clearfix" data-module="filterForm" id="list-filterForm"></div>
<div class="list-mod" id="list-mySearch"></div>
...
```

Note that, all elements with attribute `class="list-mod"` are in the result.